# How can I vectorize this (numpy) operation in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two vectors of shape `(batch, dim)`, which I'm trying to subtract from one another. Currently I am using a simple loop to subtract a specific entry in a vector (i.e. `error`) based on the second vector(i.e. `label`),from 1 :

```
per_ts_loss=0
for i, idx in enumerate(np.argmax(label, axis=1)):
    error[i, idx] -=1
    per_ts_loss += error[i, idx]
```

How Can I vectorize this?

For an example, error and label can look like this :

```
error :
array([[ 0.5488135   0.71518937  0.60276338  0.54488318  0.4236548 ]
       [ 0.64589411  0.43758721  0.891773    0.96366276  0.38344152]])
label:
    array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
           [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

for  this example, running the code below results in the following outcomes:

```
for i, idx in enumerate(np.argmax(label,axis=1)):
    error[i,idx] -=1
    ls_loss += error[i,idx]
```

result :

```
error: 
 [[ 0.5488135   0.71518937  0.60276338  0.54488318  0.4236548 ]
 [ 0.64589411  0.43758721  0.891773    0.96366276  0.38344152]]
label: 
 [[ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]

error(indexes 3 and 1 are changed): 
[[ 0.5488135   0.71518937  0.60276338 -0.45511682  0.4236548 ]
 [ 0.64589411 -0.56241279  0.891773    0.96366276  0.38344152]]
per_ts_loss: 
 -1.01752960574
```

Here is the code itself : https://ideone.com/e1k8ra

I get stuck on how to use the result of `np.argmax`, since the result is a new vector of indexes, and it cant simply be used like :

```
 error[:, np.argmax(label, axis=1)] -=1
```

So I'm stuck here!

Comment: Could you share a sample of the arrays, and the expected output?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question in a few seconds.

Comment: Also, in the last line, what is `e`, error?

Comment: @yatu: that was a typo, I fixed it. the example is also provided

Comment: Is label always 0 or 1?

Comment: yes its always 0 and 1

Comment: Simply use advanced-indexing : `error[np.arange(len(label)),np.argmax(label, axis=1)].sum()`.

Comment: if that's the case you can simply do `error - label`. And for the loss `error[label.astype('bool')].sum()`

Comment: @Divakar thats not correct. the error still needs to be retained.

Comment: @yatu: for some weird reasons, I simply cant do that, although the outcome should  be the same, but in fact they are not. this is done in an RNN backpropagarion loop, and at each timestep, the loss pertaining to that timestep needs to be subtracted. Also your op for the loss is also wrong.

Comment: @Breeze Not sure what you meant by being retained. What I meant earlier was to get `per_ts_loss` without a loop with - `per_ts_loss = error[np.arange(len(label)),np.argmax(label, axis=1)].sum()`

Comment: @Breeze tested the loss with the sample you shared, I'm getting the same result

Comment: @yatu: the loss should be `per_ts_loss:  
Out[32]: -0.7612223513633715` while running your example, I get `Out[26]: 1.2387776486366286`

Comment: @Divakar: I thought your solution was intended for error subtracted from 1! by the way for the given example error and label vectors, the per_ts_loss should be `-0.7612223513633715`

Comment: I updated the question with a snippet for easier debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
error[:, np.argmax(label, axis=1)] -=1
```

with:

```
error[np.arange(error.shape[0]), np.argmax(label, axis=1)] -=1
```

and of course

```
loss = error[np.arange(error.shape[0]), np.argmax(label, axis=1)].sum()
```

In your example you are changing, and summing, `error[0,3]` and `error[1,1]`, or in short `error[[0,1],[3,1]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
import numpy as np


error = np.array([[0.32783139, 0.29204386, 0.0572163 , 0.96162543, 0.8343454 ],
       [0.67308787, 0.27715222, 0.11738748, 0.091061  , 0.51806117]])

label= np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
           [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])



def f(error, label):
    per_ts_loss=0
    t=np.zeros(error.shape)
    argma=np.argmax(label, axis=1)
    t[[i for i in range(error.shape[0])],argma]=-1
    print(t)
    error+=t
    per_ts_loss += error[[i for i in range(error.shape[0])],argma]


f(error, label)
```

Ouput:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. -1.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but no. O dont subtract the label, the label is used to subtract 1 from the error (this is to show, how much we are away from the correct answer (i.e 1 ) 
and this is not a vectorized implementation either.